# pyspark csv reader do not separate columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to pyspark. Tried to read and modify some data directly from csv file. I have created standard file with 3 headers (A1, B2, C3) and some data below. Here is my code:

```
class Spark_fun:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

    def read_csv(self, path=None):
        return self.spark.read.csv(path, header=True, inferSchema=True)

spark = Spark_fun()
df1 = spark.read_csv("test1.csv")
df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- name;age;salary: string (nullable = true)
```

It returns only one column (all my headers binded to one string...). What Am I doing wrong? Also 2/3 header is and int type. Only first header should be string

Comment: You didn't define a seperator in `spark.read.csv()`.

Comment: @rarova, where are you learning spark/pyspark from? (just for info). Thanks.

Comment: @kishore youtube / docs